# In a MongoDB query can I use a $not clause to include nulls?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to filter my query to exclude records which have been notified in the past hour.

I tried doing this clause

```
 lastNotified: { 
    $not:{$gt:oneHourAgo}
 }
```

but that only included records which had a value for lastNotified.  Those records that did not have a lastNotified property, or whose property was null were not included.

Should I be using a $or clause to also include those records which did not have a lastNotified property, or can I do so with the $not clause.

I thought I read in the documentation that the $not clause should work.

Doing it with an or clause works but it seems like there should be a better way

```
$or: [{
   lastNotified: {
     $lt: anHourAgo
   },
 }, {
   lastNotified: {
     $exists: false
   }
 }, {
   lastNotified: null
 }]
```

Comment: It looks like your approach is correct because the $not will not account for the null values.